# tensorflow object detection faster rcnn randomly fails

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I am trying to use the new object detection api in tensorflow 1.2, and the example faster-rcnn config, to train on a custom dataset. The error I get is related to some tensor shapes, but it happens seemingly randomly during training, and the exact shape changes too.

```
INFO:tensorflow:global step 132: loss = 63.3741 (0.262 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 133: loss = 33.7362 (0.292 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 134: loss = 18.0165 (0.264 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 135: loss = 40.5577 (0.266 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 136: loss = 24.1086 (0.266 sec/step)
2017-07-10 10:23:49.066345: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1165] Invalid argument: Incompatible shapes: [1,60,4] vs. [1,64,4]
     [[Node: gradients/Loss/BoxClassifierLoss/Loss/sub_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs = BroadcastGradientArgs[T=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](gradients/Loss/BoxClassifierLoss/Loss/sub_grad/Shape, gradients/Loss/BoxClassifierLoss/Loss/sub_grad/Shape_1)]]
2017-07-10 10:23:49.066475: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1165] Invalid argument: Incompatible shapes: [1,60,4] vs. [1,64,4]
     [[Node: gradients/Loss/BoxClassifierLoss/Loss/sub_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs = BroadcastGradientArgs[T=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](gradients/Loss/BoxClassifierLoss/Loss/sub_grad/Shape, gradients/Loss/BoxClassifierLoss/Loss/sub_grad/Shape_1)]]
2017-07-10 10:23:49.066509: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1165] Invalid argument: Incompatible shapes: [1,60,4] vs. [1,64,4]
     [[Node: gradients/Loss/BoxClassifierLoss/Loss/sub_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs = BroadcastGradientArgs[T=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](gradients/Loss/BoxClassifierLoss/Loss/sub_grad/Shape, gradients/Loss/BoxClassifierLoss/Loss/sub_grad/Shape_1)]]
INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError'>, Incompatible shapes: [1,60,4] vs. [1,64,4]
     [[Node: gradients/Loss/BoxClassifierLoss/Loss/sub_grad/BroadcastGradientArgs = BroadcastGradientArgs[T=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](gradients/Loss/BoxClassifierLoss/Loss/sub_grad/Shape, gradients/Loss/BoxClassifierLoss/Loss/sub_grad/Shape_1)]]
     [[Node: gradients/FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_50/resnet_v1_50/block1/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/conv3/convolution_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1/_2621 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_13108_gradients/FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_50/resnet_v1_50/block1/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/conv3/convolution_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

As you can see, it runs for a variable number of steps correctly, and then gives me `Invalid argument: Incompatible shapes: [1,60,4] vs. [1,64,4]`. What I dont understand is why this error is being triggered, and furthermore the where the incompatible shape comes from, as this changes as well between runs.

As I did convert my dataset into the TF format, I was unsure whether that was my issue. However, I have successfully trained for several days on the same dataset with their ssd implementation, so I think it is safe to say the data is formatted correctly.

EDIT: The label map file is [here](https://pastebin.com/f3K4q2ZR). Again I would like to point out that this same dataset runs perfectly using ssd.

Comment: I sometimes see this error with invalid label maps.  Can you copy your labelmap into the question?

Comment: updated with the label map

Comment: I am facing the same issue. The dataset is getting trained with SSD but getting error after 136 global steps while using f_rcnn. My label map id starts from 1. Any idea how to overcome this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tensorflow Object Detection API assumes that the '0' label is reserved for 'none_of_the_above', so one immediate thing to do is to add 1 to every label index in your label map.

It's unclear why things fail (in a hard way) for Faster R-CNN and not for SSD (probably something for us to dig into) --- but I'd be a bit surprised if you got very good results with SSD using that label map.

Comment: is none of the above in this case background or just unknown? the evaluation doesn't run fully (the other issue open) but some of the results look really good. ill try change the label map and retrain.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to start your class id from 1 instead of 0.

```
item {
  id: 1
  name: 'balloon'
}
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure `num_classes = xx` in **faster_rcnn_resnet101.config** file

Answer (score 0):

You are reading your sequence examples from `tf.train.batch` with `allow_smaller_final_batch=True`. The error likely could be the last smaller final batch which is resulting in incompatible shapes with batch sizes